# Is it possible to operate against a non-local remote cert store without COM/Interop?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

I've been banging my head against a CA database with a `new X509Store("\\server\folder", StoreLocation.Local)` statement and can not get it to work since this requires elevated priv's. The internet tells me I need to invoke some COM libs and that will work [1](http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2009/02/reading-x509-certificates-from-remote.html). Is there any way to get around this without COM?

Comment: It is not COM, just pinvoke for winapi functions.  The same ones that X509Store uses.  Done poorly, the declarations are wrong and won't be reliable for 64-bit code.  The odds that pinvoke will solve a security access problem are never good, just try it.  If it works then you'll get somewhere, if it doesn't solve your problem then avoid asking an XY question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO. Windows certificate store provide only one API type which is implemented in a C++ functions which can be accessed from .NET only by using interop.

Actually, `X509Store` .NET class is just a wrapper over native functions.